# How to supply named colors to the scale_x_manual in ggplot2 >=3.3.4

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I have a code generating power point presentations from weekly data.
My table with row materials contain the material used in that week. Additionally I have a named vector with all the materials ever used and assigned colors to them. This ensures that Mat1 is always the same color weather or not it is used that week.

This is how it is programmed:

```
ggplot(df, aes(fill=Mat, y=pct, x=Date)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors)
```

upto ggplot2 3.3.3 it was working fine. New 3.3.4 version changes the scale_xx_manual function which takes all the names from values and apply it to limits. This generates very long legend to the plot with all the possible color values even if only 3-4 are used that week.

I can go around it supplying

```
values = colors[unique(df$Mat)]
```

but that does not seem to be elegant solution.

Making use of the `ggplot2::mpg` dataset a minimal reproducible example of the issue:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

colors <- scales::hue_pal()(length(unique(mpg$class)))
colors <- setNames(colors, unique(mpg$class))

x <- subset(mpg, mpg$class %in% c("compact", "subcompact", "2seater"))

ggplot(x, aes(x = class, fill=class)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors)
```

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: This looks like a "bug" introduced with the latest ggplot2. See https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4511. As a workaround you could use `limits=force` as suggested by [@teunbrand](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4511#issuecomment-866185530)

Comment: Yes that workaround should work, but really any non-`NULL` limits should work. Force is doing nothing more in this case than returning the input verbatim.